# How to change chart series name with extender in p:chart?

Tags: primefaces, charts, jqplot

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  function decimal() {

    this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions = {
      formatString: '%#.2f'
    };

    this.cfg.seriesDefaults.rendererOptions.varyBarColor = true;

    this.cfg.series = [{
      seriesColors: ["#00BFFF", "#00BFFF", "#00BFFF", "#00BFFF", "#00BFFF", "#00BFFF", "#00BFFF"]
    }, {
      seriesColors: ["#FF4000", "#FF4000", "#FF4000", "#FF4000", "#FF4000", "#FF4000", "#FF4000"]
    }, ]
  }

< /script>
```

This is the extender. I already set series label but when I run application series label don't display on chart. Showing series1 and series 2. When I deactive extender series label display on chart. I have to change color of bar so I'm using extender.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a solution with extender. Because extender convert default values of chart. I changed my chatseries loops. I set same group of value each chartseries then deactivate extender. Problem is solved. To change colour of bar you can use model of chart attribute "setseriesColors".